# Any tool to generate html form 

Tags: html, json, forms, dynamic

I want to generate html form based on json response from server. In JSON response there will be input type , input title all necessay information. It can be checbox , radio button , texarea or any any input.

Is there any third party tool  to generate the form.

Thanks .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the dhtmlx forms javascript library:

http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxForm/index.shtml

You can create forms on the fly with xml/json as datasource

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Ext JS 4:
http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/

There is a sample for dynamic forms created from JSON:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/form/dynamic.html

Also look at the Ext Designer, to create the Javascript to render these forms:
http://www.sencha.com/products/designer/

Ext JS 4 has both commercial and GNU GPL license v3 but the designer is commercial with a 30-day trial.