# Generate JSON from a form

Tags: json, code-generation

I'm looking for the inverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376618/any-tool-to-generate-html-form) in that I seek a utility that can consume a rendered (view source) HTML page/form and generate the JSON that can represent that form's posting. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376618/any-tool-to-generate-html-form)

The answer suggested [http://www.jsonschema.net](http://www.jsonschema.net/) is close in format - JSON schema to/from JSON code - I want to paste in an HTML form and see the JSON stubbed out.

thx

Comment: what if you write a function that given a `<form>` it will generate the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$fn.serializeForm = function()
{
 var o = {};
  var a = this.serializeArray();
  $.each(a, function() {
      if (o[this.name]) {
          if (!o[this.name].push) {
              o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
          }
          o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
      } else {
          o[this.name] = this.value || '';
      }
  });

 return o;
}
```

Then call:

```
$('form').serializeForm();
```